# Prove that $\langle 2+i\rangle$ is a maximal ideal for Gaussian Integers $\Bbb Z[i]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

There is a solution which starts by taking $\langle 2+i\rangle$ as a subset of $\langle a+ib\rangle $ and then proceeds as, Hence $(2+i)$ can be represented as multiple of $(a+ib)$. I understand till this part.

Next it proceeds, $(2+i)=(a+ib)(c+id)$. I don't understand this line.

Shouldn't it proceed by multiplying $(a+ib)$ with an integer. 
Why is $(a+ib)$  multiplied with another complex number?

Comment: The quotient is a field, hence the ideal is maximal.

Comment: The author means a multiple by an element of the ring $\Bbb Z[i]$.

Comment: @Bernard Why so? Under which property will this statement be correct. I was thinking that, since a+ib is generator, so he meant that multiplying with some integer will give 2+i

Comment: A prinipal ideal is contained in another principal ideal if the generator of the former is a multiple of the generator of the latter by  an element of the ring. Itis not a question about abelian groups, but about rings.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Bernard